# Getting DISTINCT ids in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table structure like this:

```
Comments table
id      review_id    user_id  created     comments deleted
1       10           28       2011-10-12  "hi"     0
2       11           28       2011-10-13  "yo"     0
3       10           28       2011-10-15  "bye"    0
```

I want to get the latest comment from each review sorted by created DESC.  So I have something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT review_id, 'comments' as type FROM comments as MyTable WHERE 
user_id=28 AND deleted=0 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 30
```

So in the above table I want the rows for id = 3 and then id = 2 returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example Query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2143/getting-distinct-ids-in-mysql

```
SELECT id,comment
FROM comments
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM comments
    WHERE user_id=28 AND deleted=0
    GROUP BY review_id )
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Comment: how would i add in other columns

Comment: can you give full table structure

Comment: lets say a comment field i want returned to

Comment: added full structure, i want to get the latest row of all the columns grouped by review_id

Comment: oh and i need the "comments" as type (i'm combining some data and need to keep track of which query this is from

Comment: that's not quite right, you can't do a max(comments), i need the comment that belongs to the row with max(id)

Comment: inner query select max id, outer query select comments

Answer (score 1):

Please integrate this code in your code.

Table data:

```
id      review_id    user_id  created     comments deleted
1       10           28       2011-10-12  "hi"     0
2       11           28       2011-10-13  "yo"     0
3       10           28       2011-10-15  "bye"    0
```

Run query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, review_id, 'comments' AS TYPE 
FROM mytable
WHERE user_id = 28
AND deleted = 0
AND id = (
  SELECT max( id )
  FROM mytable 
)
```

Result:

```
id  review_id    TYPE
3   10       comments
```